# Why it is mandatory to pass column names to INSERT statement when we have default Getdate() column?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `Student` and I have an identity column and date column with a configured default of `GETDATE()`. Here is the query which works when I pass the column names along with values, but it doesn't work when I don't pass column names.

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Grade VARCHAR(5),
    Created_Date DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
)

INSERT INTO Student (Name, Grade) 
VALUES ( 'Uma', 'A+') 

SELECT Top 1 * FROM Student

DROP TABLE Student
GO
```

This doesn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Grade VARCHAR(5),
    Created_Date DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
)

INSERT INTO Student 
VALUES ( 'Uma', 'A+') -- without column names

SELECT Top 1 * FROM Student

DROP TABLE Student
GO
```

I know that a table can have only one identity column but when I am able to insert default `GETDATE()` without even passing date column name. What could be the logical reason to pass the column names to insert statement when I have date column as default?

Comment: Without explicit columns it assumes column references are "in order" beginning at the first one and not just columns that require explicit values. It's a bad practice to rely on any ordering anyway and I doubt that the SQL standard condones this variation so as to reinforce that idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify the columns, then you are implicitly stating you are inserting values into **all** the columns, and thus must define those values. A `DEFAULT` value is only used if you explicitly state `DEFAULT` in the `VALUES` clause or omit the column entirely from the `INTO` clause.

As such `INSERT INTO Student VALUES...` is equivalent to `INSERT INTO Students ([Name], Grade, Created_Date) VALUES...` and in the above, you don't provide a value for `Created_Date` so the statement fails.

If you really *don't* want to include the columns (which is ill-advised) use `DEFAULT` in the `VALUES` clause:

```sql
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES ( 'Uma', 'A+',DEFAULT)
```